# How to count unchanged occurrence of values within a group

Tags: python, pandas, run-length-encoding

Let's assume I've got a `DataFrame` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'measurement_id': np.repeat([1, 2], [30, 30]),
                             'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6]), 
                                                    np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6, 6])]),
                             'obj': list('ABCDEF' * 10),
                             'var': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                                     1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2,                                                           
                                     2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
                                     2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]})
```

So there are 2 measurements that measure some `var` value for 6 objects in one minute breaks. What I'd like to do is to create a column that would count how long (how many minutes) each `var` value wasn't changing. I think it could be achieved by appropriate `groupby`, equivalent to R function `data.table::rleid` that creates run-length type id column and finally counting how many minutes were within one value of the resulting column.

So the resulting output would be as follows:

```
df['rleid_output'] = np.concatenate([[1] * 18, [2] * 12, [3] * 6, [4] * 18, [5] * 6])
df['expected_output'] = np.concatenate([[3] * 18, [2] * 12, [1] * 6, [3] * 18, [1] * 6])
```

Unfortunetely, I don't know how can it can be done in Pandas. I'm struggling both with creating `rleid` equivalent as well as obtaining `expected_output` then. Any ideas how `expected_output` could be achieved, no matter if using `rleid` equivalent or not?

@Edit: To answer comments about the logic of 'expected_output', here's how I compute it in my head:

- For 1st minute within 1st measurement we have following pairs of `obj` and `var`: (A, 1), (B, 1), (C, 2), (D, 2), (E, 2), (F, 2)
- In 2nd and 3rd minute of measurement 1 those pairs remain unchanged, so the first assignment last for at least 3 minutes
- In 4th minute `var` value changes to 1 for `obj = C`. At least one pair has changed, so our whole assignment is treated as changed and starts new value of `rleid_output`. At the same time we already know that previous assignment lasted for exactly 3 minutes and value of `expected_output` should be set to 3 for all previous rows. Current assignment (`obj`, `var`) is (A, 1), (B, 1), (C, 1), (D, 2), (E, 2), (F, 2).
- In 5th minute assignment didn't changed. Next group of (`measurement_id`, `min`) is actually new measurement, so as it was our final minute we know already that we should set `expected_output` to 2 in rows having `(measurement_id, min) == (1, 4)` and `(measurement_id, min) == (1, 5)` as assignment was the same for 2 minutes.
- Next group of rows is new measurement `(measurement_id, min) == (2, 1)`. It starts with assignment (A, 2), (B, 2), (C, 1), (D, 1), (E, 2), (F, 2). It changes in the next minute so we can mark it as the assignment that lasts for only 1 minute (value of `expected_output`).
- Next assignment is (A, 2), (B, 1), (C, 1), (D, 1), (E, 2), (F, 2) and it lasts for 3 minutes - that's why `expected_output = 3` for rows from 36 to 53.
- In final, 5th minute of measurement 2, F changes `var` value to 2, so we have new assignment ((A, 2), (B, 1), (C, 1), (D, 1), (E, 2), (F, 1)) that lasts for 1 minute only as we don't have further measurements.

I hope it's clearer now.

Also, it would be good to know how it can be done with individual assignment changes, i.e. if we don't treat assignment as a whole, but rather individual pairs e.g. (A, 2)

@Edit2: Shortened example, as requested, below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'measurement_id': np.repeat([1, 2], [6, 6]),
                         'min': np.concatenate([np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2]), 
                                                np.repeat([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2])]),
                         'obj': list('AB' * 6),
                         'var': [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
df['rleid_output'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
df['expected_output'] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `expected_output` just counts how many minutes values of `var` remains unchanged. So you can obtain it as follows: if `var` value for any `obj` has changed in comparison with the previous minute, you get new value of `rleid_output`. Then `expected_output` just counts unique values of `min` within the same value of `rleid_output`.

Comment: I'm still not clear what `rleid_output` and `expected_output` is supposed to be? Can you may be add a simple example (+ walkthrough) of how `rleid_output` and `expected_output` are computed?

Comment: @thushv89, I have edited the post to incorporate detailed workthrough.

Comment: @anky_91, as requested, I have put the example shortened to 12 rows (I think it's minimal to incorporate all quirks) at the bottom

Comment: @anky_91, those question are different (please note the difference in `rleid_output` and `expected_output`). Here, the new run id should be assigned to all `obj` within the same group in case of `measurement_id` or `var` has changed for any `obj`. Could you please reopen?

Comment: @jakes i see, repoened